# How to search for and return all records between two dates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup, lookup

I'm not sure if this is a lookup formula I need. Basically, I have a huge spreadsheet with the travel details of lots and lots of groups. Each row is a different group. For reference, Column K shows their outbound date, and Column M their return date. The columns run to Column N in total.

In a separate sheet (Sheet 2) I want to be able to input a date range (eg 1st November - 7th November) and return every group that is travelling between these two dates. I'm sure there's a way to do it but I just can't think of how. LOOKUP isn't working for me, so I think I'm doing it wrong.

Can anyone suggest something?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you are right that a vlookup will not solve your problem. Why not filter the data in your original table? Then if needed, copy and paste to your second sheet. I do suspect you may need a helper column as there may be cases where travel could start/end outside of the date range.